# По нажатию на кнопку, показать текущее значение QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qcombobox

Есть программа, которая при нажатие кнопки выдаёт в `QMessageBox` строку с названием фильма.

Ранее не сталкивался с `QComboBox`. 
Пожалуйста, помогите.

**Console.py**:

```
import random

a = [       #Боевик
"Безумный Макс: Дорога ярости\n2015 г.\nIMDb: 8,1",
"Малыш на драйве\n2017 г.\nIMDb: 7,7",
"Мстители\n2012 г.\nIMDb: 8,1"
]

b = [       #Военный
"Атака на Перл Харбор\n2011 г.\nIMDb: 6.8",
"Ярость\n2014 г.\nIMDb: 7.6",
"Спасти рядового Райана\n1998 г.\nIMDb: 8.6"
]

c = [       #Детектив
"Зеленая миля\n1999 г.\nIMDb: 8.5",
"Начало\n2010 г.\nIMDb: 8.8",
"Престиж\n2006 г.\nIMDb: 8.5"
]

while True:
    rez = (input("Введите жанр (a,b,c): "))
    if rez == 'a':
        print (random.choice(a))
    elif rez == 'b':
        print (random.choice(b))
    elif rez == 'c':
        print (random.choice(c))
    else:
        break
    print()
```

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from design import *                #UI file
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку  
    def MyFunction(self):
    pass
       
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**design.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200, 220)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 220))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 220))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Icons8-Ios7-Cinema-Documentary.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setAccessibleName("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 151, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 121, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 111, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 121, 22))
        self.comboBox.setMaxVisibleItems(8)
        self.comboBox.setFrame(True)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Know You Better"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Помочь Вам выбрать фильм?!"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Нажмите на меня"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите жанр"))
        self.comboBox.setCurrentText(_translate("MainWindow", "Боевик"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Боевик"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Военный"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Детектив"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробуйте:

main.py

```
import sys

# Импортируем наш интерфейс из файла

from designUi import *                #design
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

        self.comboText = "Боевик"
        self.ui.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText)

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется при нажатии на кнопку  

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onActivatedText(self, text):
        self.comboText = text     

    def MyFunction(self):
        if self.comboText:
            print("Вы выбрали жанр: {}".format(self.comboText))
        else:
            print("Выберите жанр.")


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

designUi.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200, 220)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 220))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 220))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Icons8-Ios7-Cinema-Documentary.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setAccessibleName("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 151, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 121, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 111, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 121, 22))
        self.comboBox.setMaxVisibleItems(8)
        self.comboBox.setFrame(True)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Know You Better"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Помочь Вам выбрать фильм?!"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Нажмите на меня"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите жанр"))
        self.comboBox.setCurrentText(_translate("MainWindow", "Боевик"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Боевик"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Военный"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Детектив"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Круто! Большое спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!